# Como adicionar um rodapé dinâmico no WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou a fazer um site em WordPress e queria saber se existe algum *plugin* que faça um rodapé a correr, sendo que posso alterar o conteúdo do rodapé no *backoffice*.

Não tenho código pois não sei como fazer. Queria ter tipo no *backoffice* uma opção que seja rodapé e depois posso alterar o conteúdo e depois no código só tenho de chamar esse *plugin*.

Comment: E se não houver plugin? Pode detalhar melhor isto *"sendo que posso alterar o conteúdo do rodapé no backoffice"*?

Comment: se não houver plugin tenho de fazer um

Comment: queria ter tipo no backoffice uma opção que seja rodapé e depois posso alterar o conteudo e depois no código só tenho de chamar esse plugin..

Comment: você poderia utilizar um slider como rodapé cara, oq acha? se concordar eu crio uma resposta;

Answer (score 1):

Se quiser fazer uma opção no *backend* que seja dentro da área de Ajustes, tem que usar o [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API). Para fazer dentro dos ajustes do Theme tem que usar a [Theme Customization API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API). Cada uma delas tem funções para serem chamadas no *frontend* e puxar os valores.

Outra maneira fácil é criar um [Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) onde pode registrar mais de uma opção de rodapé e puxar no frontend com a função [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).

Neste plugin de exemplo, estou criando um post type que só suporta títulos, ver `supports => array(SUAS-OPÇÕES)`:

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: Rodapés personalizados
 * Plugin URI: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/98553/201
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: brasofilo
 */

add_action( 'init', 'footers_custom_init' );

# Ajustar $labels e $args conforme suas necessidades
function footers_custom_init() {
  $labels = array(
    'name' => 'Footers',
    'singular_name' => 'Footer',
    'add_new' => 'Add New',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Footer',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Footer',
    'new_item' => 'New Footer',
    'all_items' => 'All Footers',
    'view_item' => 'View Footer',
    'search_items' => 'Search Footers',
    'not_found' =>  'No teasers found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No teasers found in Trash', 
    'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Page',
    'menu_name' => 'Footers'
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'description' => '',
    'public' => false,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(),
    'capability_type' => 'page',
    'has_archive' => false, 
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'menu_position' => 60,
    'supports' => array( 'title')
  ); 

  register_post_type( 'footers', $args );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'imprime_rodape' ) ) {
    # Ajustar $args conforme suas necessidades
    function imprime_rodape() {
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 'orderby' => 'rand', 'post_type' => 'footers' );
        $rand_footer = get_posts( $args );        
        echo $rand_footer[0]->post_title;
    }
}
```

Depois, no arquivo `footer.php` do seu *theme*, usar a seguinte função do plugin para imprimir um rodapé aleatório:

```
<?php if ( function_exists( 'imprime_rodape' ) ) imprime_rodape(); ?>
```

Comment: dá para por sempre o ultimo footer adicionado...isto é para um site de apostas